# Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong? The first 2 parts of the code work and the picture shows up when it can link to the jpg but I also want the screen to say who wins.

```
<html> <body>
<html>
<H1>Choose Wisely...</H1>
<img src="RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock2.jpg" id="bg" alt="">

<title>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h2><p>Your Choice:</p>
<form action="form_action.asp">
  <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Rock" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" >Rock<br>
  <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Paper" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" >Paper<br>
  <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Scissors" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" >Scissors<br>
  <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Lizard" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" >Lizard <br>
  <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Spock" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" >Spock<br><br>
</form>

<h2> Computer Choice: <p id="computer"></p>
<p id="compare"></p></h2>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var computer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5)+1); 
    if (computer == 1) {computer = "Rock";
}
else if (computer == 2) {computer = "Paper";
}
else if (computer == 3) {computer = "Scissors";
}
else if (computer == 4) {computer = "Lizard";
}
else if (computer == 5) {computer = "Spock";
}
    document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML = computer;}
</script>
<script>
var compare = function (choice1,choice2);
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        result "Draw, try again!";
    }
    else
    {
        if(choice1 === "Rock")
        {
            if(choice2 === "Paper")
            {
            result ("Paper covers Rock. You lose.");
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            result ("Rock crushes Scissors. You win.");
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Lizard")
        {
            result ("Rock smashes Lizard. You win.");
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Spock")
        {
            result ("Spock vaporizes Rock. You lose.");
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    if(choice1 === "Paper")
        {
        if(choice2 === "Rock")
        {
           return "Paper covers Rock. You Win.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return "Scissors cut Paper. You lose.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Lizard")
        {
            return "Lizard eats Paper. You lose.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Spock")
        {
            return "Paper disproves Spock. You Win.";
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        if(choice1 === "Scissors")
        {
        if(choice2 === "Rock")
        {
           return "Rock beats Scissors. You lose.";
        }
        if(choice2 === "Paper")
        {
           return "Scissors cut Paper. You win.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Lizard")
        {
            return "Scissors decapitate Lizard. You win.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Spock")
        {
            return "Spock smashes Scissors. You lose.";
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        if(choice1 === "Lizard")
        {
        if(choice2 === "Rock")
        {
           return "Rock smashes Lizard. You lose.";
        }
        if(choice2 === "Paper")
        {
           return "Lizard eats Paper. You win.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return "Scissors decapitate Lizard. You lose.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Spock")
        {
            return "Lizard poisons Spock. You win.";
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        if(choice1 === "Spock")
        {
        if(choice2 === "Rock")
        {
           return "Spock vaporizes Rock. You win.";
        }
        if(choice2 === "Paper")
        {
           return "Paper disproves Spock. You lose.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Lizard")
        {
            return "Lizard poisons Spock. You lose.";
        }
        else if(choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return "Spock smashes Scissors. You win.";
        }
                }
                }
                };
    compare(id,computer);
```

I have tried `console.log(compare(id,computer))` and    `document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = compare;}` neither worked

also tried changing id to an integer and adding

```
function myFunction(myText) {
    if computer == 1 and id == 1{
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Rock vs Rock, Stalemate!"}
    else if computer == 1 and id == 2{
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Paper Covers Rock,Loser!"}
    else if computer == 1 and  id == 3{
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Rock Crushes Scissors, Winner!"}
    else if computer == 1 and id == 4{
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Rock Crushes Lizard, Winner!"}
    else if computer == 1 and  id == 5{
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Spock Vaporizes Rock, Loser!"}
}
</script>
```

Comment: you have semicoln after `function (choice1, choice2)` then you proceeded with a curly brace which will generate an error i presume.

Answer (score 1):

### [Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qbFfzMgfYg65QPZ6EqGK)

Most information is added in comments below in the code.

There were multiple issues with your code, mainly the way you handled `else if`.  Please note, the below code is still very poorly written and can be optimized.

Also you were calling `compare(id, computer)` but `id` was undefined.  In addition you were passing `this.value` onclick of the radio buttons but this doesn't work because the value of all of them was `on`, this is changed to `this.id` below as that will pass the expected value.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- moved from head to body -->
  <H1>Choose Wisely...</H1>
  <!-- moved from head to body -->
  <img src="RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock2.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
  <!-- changed <p> to <div> added </h2> to the end -->
  <h2><div>Your Choice:</div></h2>
  <form action="form_action.asp">
    <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Rock" value="1" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Rock
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Paper" value="2" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Paper
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Scissors" value="3" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Scissors
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Lizard" value="4" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Lizard
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="userchoice" id="Spock" value="5" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Spock
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>

  <!-- changed <p> to <div> -->
  <h2>Computer Choice: <div id="computer"></div>
<div id="compare"></div></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
// Code goes here

function myFunction(value) {
  var computer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  if (computer == 1) {
    computer = "Rock";
  } else if (computer == 2) {
    computer = "Paper";
  } else if (computer == 3) {
    computer = "Scissors";
  } else if (computer == 4) {
    computer = "Lizard";
  } else if (computer == 5) {
    computer = "Spock";
  }

  document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML = computer;
  //added compare call and updating the innerHTML of the compare id DOM object
  document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = compare(value, computer);
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    // changed to return
    return "Draw, try again!";
  } 
  //changed to else if instead of else {
  else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
    if (choice2 === "Paper") {
      return "Paper covers Rock. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
      return "Rock crushes Scissors. You win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
      return "Rock smashes Lizard. You win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
      return "Spock vaporizes Rock. You lose.";
    }
  } 
  //changed to else if instead of else {
  else if (choice1 === "Paper") {
    if (choice2 === "Rock") {
      return "Paper covers Rock. You Win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
      return "Scissors cut Paper. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
      return "Lizard eats Paper. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
      return "Paper disproves Spock. You Win.";
    }
  }
  //changed to else if instead of else {
  else if (choice1 === "Scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "Rock") {
      return "Rock beats Scissors. You lose.";
    }
    //changed to else if instead of if {
    else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
      return "Scissors cut Paper. You win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
      return "Scissors decapitate Lizard. You win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
      return "Spock smashes Scissors. You lose.";
    }
  }
  //changed to else if instead of else {
  else if (choice1 === "Lizard") {
    if (choice2 === "Rock") {
      return "Rock smashes Lizard. You lose.";
    }
    //changed to else if instead of if {
    else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
      return "Lizard eats Paper. You win.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
      return "Scissors decapitate Lizard. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Spock") {
      return "Lizard poisons Spock. You win.";
    }
  } 
  //changed to else if instead of else {
  else if (choice1 === "Spock") {
    if (choice2 === "Rock") {
      return "Spock vaporizes Rock. You win.";
    }
    //changed to else if instead of if {
    else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
      return "Paper disproves Spock. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Lizard") {
      return "Lizard poisons Spock. You lose.";
    } else if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
      return "Spock smashes Scissors. You win.";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you assistance.